# How to change datetime format according to web site accessing on timezone asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to understand this concept and implement it into my application. Since, suppose I have deployed my asp.net mvc web application at US server. and If I am showing the datetime on my one of the page, say in grid control. and consider somebody accessing site from the UK or India Or Gulf then the date time format should be change accordingly. 
Also the datetime input controls should be behave accordingly. What concept i need to use for this?

Comment: timezone is not a good variant, because in one timezone can be countries with different date formats. The best choise, use the user language from request.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages(v=vs.110).aspx should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand  where request came from.
You can analyze timezone(example [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)), user language or check client ip adress. After that you can use correctly formated date string.

Edit:

interesting topic from msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Why not just using the culture from the browser?

Comment: @Highace2, how can you get culture from request?

Comment: @Frank59 - Thread.CurrentUICulture contains user culture info.

Comment: @ Alexander, i think that Thread.CurrentUICulture  contains server culture settings. But may be parameter enableClientBasedCulture in web.config change this situation.

Comment: @Frank59, Thread.CurrentUICulture contains culture for the current user context. For the asp.net web application this context initialized from request header params. And yes, enableClientBasedCulture can change this behavoir.

Comment: @Frank59 Maybe use HttpRequest.UserLanguages?